# leap year, and the boolean logic behind it

Tags: python

The rules for leap year is :
(1) Most years that can be divided evenly by 4 are leap years.

(2) Century years are NOT leap years UNLESS they can be evenly divided by 400.

I can't help but think I should AND everywhere  `if ( y%4==0 and y%100!=0 and y%400 == 0 ):`
  which I know is wrong but why exactly ?

This is the real solution :

```
def year_days(y):
  if ( y%4==0 and y%100!=0 ) or ( y%400 == 0 ):
    return True

return False
```

Comment: Place parentheses to group your conditions properly

Comment: okay, added it....

Comment: If you put all _and_, the year has to be divisible by 4 _and_ divisible by 400 to be a leap year. In other words, just every 400 years at most. Add _and not divisible by 100_ and no years will be leap years at all.

Comment: @Kay : he is asking why he can't "and" everywhere.

Comment: Related to the task but unrelated to the question, `import calendar` `return calendar.isleap(y)` works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the year 2004. Now `2004 % 4 = 0 , 2004 % 100 != 0 , 2004 % 400 != 0` So last condition fails and so it will give you false despite 2004 is a leap year.

Logic behind the boolean logic :

Century years are NOT leap years UNLESS they can be evenly divided by 400. --- > This gives you that all years divided by 400 will be leap for sure BUT all years divided by 100 may be not.

Most years that can be divided evenly by 4 are leap years. --- > Any year divided by 4 is a leap year other than some of those century years

So now think it this way :  `y divisible by 400` is always leap . 
Also y divisible by 4 is always leap unless they are not century years (Exclude years % 400 as they have been taken care of previously). So this gives rise to the condition : `y%4 == 0 and y%100 != 0` As if one of them fails the year is not leap. 
Also, now if  `(y%4 == 0 and y%100 != 0)` is true or `(y%400 == 0)` is true, the year is leap , so you put an or between them giving you :

`(y%4 == 0 and y%100 != 0) or (y%400 == 0)`

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think what I want to know is how to translate the rules of leap year (English) to appropriate boolean logic. I'm getting lost as to when to use AND or OR...

Comment: Updated the answer with a detailed explanation

Comment: @airnet: Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`y % 400 == 0` *implies* `y % 4 == 0` and `y % 100 == 0`, so `and`ing with `y % 4 == 0` is useless and `and`ing with `y % 100 != 0` leads to an expression that's always false.

Comment: It might help OP if you described how to express an implication with AND/OR/NOT.